# PHP numeric separator, setlocale

Tags: php, locale, setlocale

I've recently come upon a very intriguing issue. I have the following code on a website to generate a number composed by 10 digits, followed by a period (.), followed by 2 to 4 digits. I also use the gettext function to translate the page into 2 other different languages

```
<?php
      $lang = "en_UK";
      putenv("LC_ALL=$lang");
      setlocale(LC_ALL, $lang);
      bindtextdomain("messages", "locale");
      bind_textdomain_codeset('messages', 'UTF-8');
      textdomain("messages");

      list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ",microtime());
      $my_number = ((float)$usec + (float)$sec + (float)rand(1, 100000000));
?>
      <form method ="POST" action="">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $my_number; ?>"/>
          <input type="submit"/>
      </form>
```

So far so good. When `$lang` is equal to **en_UK**, I get what I need (1234567891.1234).

But if `$lang` is equal to **it_IT**, or **de_DE**, then `$my_number` changes format to 10 digits, followed by a **COMMA**, followed by 2 to 4 digits (1234567891,1234).

Does anybody now why this happens???
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different countries have different conventions about how to write numerals. [`setlocale`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) changes the conventions your program uses.

Comment: Well, that explains it all. Thanks a lot!!!! As far as you know... is there any way to avoid this specific behaviour without going crazy? :)

Comment: @iosononando: You may need to search for or ask another question. I do not work in PHP and cannot advise about using multiple locales in PHP.

Comment: Fair enough Eric. I'll go around the problem this time. Thanks again!

Comment: It's an old question, but the solution to this would be to perhaps only set `LC_MESSAGES`, or to reset the `LC_NUMERIC` locale back to `en`.